# How can I mount disks via cron in Mountain Lion?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, cron

Is there a way to mount disks in Mountain Lion that works with cron?

The following command works fine from the Terminal:

```
/usr/sbin/diskutil mount disk1s6
```

But when executed via my crontab, it fails. My crontab is working fine, otherwise.

I've been using cron to mount my backup disk once a day before I do a smart clone via SuperDuper. (Possibly related... the SuperDuper release notes mention problems mounting drives in Mountain Lion, but I want to emphasize I was mounting drives separately using a shell script and/or cron.)

Any ideas or potential workarounds for this problem?

Comment: How does it fail, do you get any error messages?

Comment: It fails silently with no error messages.

Comment: And you are sure it gets run at all?

Comment: Yes, other cron tasks execute properly.

Comment: I never found a solution for this, so I'm using LaunchAgents (via Lingon 3) instead. Works great!

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and found that I could get it to work if the cron job was launched under root.

[This Apple discussion link](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4257710?start=0&tstart=0) has this note:

> [...] Basically, Apple is tracking where an application launches from,
>   and seems to be preventing processes that launch from "cron" (one of
>   the system schedulers), even indirectly, from mounting local disk
>   volumes, even when that application is signed.